# Are session IDs obtained by WTSEnumerateSessions API unique?

Tags: c++, winapi, sessionid

Say, if at one point in time I call [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a local service application and obtain the list of current user session IDs. So if at some later time I need to know if some particular user session is still in the same state, can I rely on [WTS_SESSION_INFO::SessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be unique? And if not, how to do this?

Comment: What would you consider a change of state ? If the user was logged on and is now locked, would you say that the session is in the same state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows gives a SID to every logon session. [MSDN has sample code to look it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it is guaranteed to be unique and constant for a given logon session. If the user logs out and logs back in again, he will be attributed a new Logon SID.

If the same user is logged locally and logged on remotely at the same, there will be a different Logon SID for each logon session. This image shows what I mean :

[image: Alice has two logon session, with distinct Logon SID].

(Disclaimer - I stole it from a [blog post of mine](http://www.paralint.com/blog/2007/12/19/getting-the-username-from-a-desktop-handle-hdesk/))

You can get the Logon SID with this command. It can be useful to play what-if scenarios without writing any code.

```
c:\>whoami /logonid
S-1-5-5-0-329693570
```

Tested on Windows Server 2008. YMMV on other versions.

Edit: **Fixed Grammatical Errors**

Comment: Good explanation, diagram (although self-plagiarized) and the C++ code. Although I have one question about the code sample. It uses a token handle to look up the logon SID, but I do not have a token. Or, should I say, how do I get it?

Comment: @user843732 You use [WTSQueyUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the token. The application making the call ***MUST*** be running in the context of the local system account and have the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege for the call to work.

Answer (score 2):

Session id is assigned as the lowest unused number at the time of login.

So if I had ID 1, then logged off, and you log on you would get ID 1 too as 1 was available when you logged on.

If I never logged off you would get ID 2 due to ID 1 was in use. If I then logoff and you stay on the next user will be assigned ID 1 again (not 3) because 1 was the lowest unused number.

Comment: So what is the point of session IDs returned by that API? That ID becomes invalid as soon as it's returned because in that interim a user might have logged out and a new user might have logged in and the new user will have the same session ID...

Comment: It is assumed that you would query the ID then immediately do whatever you needed that required you to pass in the ID as a parameter, for example broadcasting a message to all logged on users you would call WTSEnumerateSessions and for each result you immediately call [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will take under a second to do both of those operations and it is highly unlikely that a person will have logged of, and another person will have logged on in the fraction of the second between those two calls.

Comment: Another common and useful example is if I want a utility to log someone off. I would call WTSEnumerateSessions once to populate my UI, when the user makes a choice of who to log off, I call WTSEnumerateSessions again, I check that the username and the SessionID are still the same as what I had displayed in the UI (in case the user had logged off in the intervening time) I then call [WTSLogoffSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to log off the user by passing in the session ID I just checked and I knew was valid.

Comment: Regarding your second example with logging off a user. So, say I display a user context menu with user accounts to log off. But how would each be identified? I obviously can't use session IDs obtained from this API because in this scenario a session Id can easily change while a user is making their choice?

Comment: Each would be identified by the login name for the user, also Session ID's do not change "All the time" it happens only when someone logs on or off, and that is not that relatively common.

Comment: Sorry, Scott, I do not agree with you on this one. Say, on a terminal services system a user can log in or log out while my context menu is shown. So as the result, the session ID that a menu item holds will point to a different user session and my app may log out the wrong user.

Comment: That is why I included the section "I check that the username and the SessionID are still the same as what I had displayed in the UI (in case the user had logged off in the intervening time)" in my example in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

A session ID is not the same as a security ID.  A session might have someone logged into it in some state, or might not have someone logged into it.  You could call WTSEnumerateSessions and find that someone is logged in at session 1, later that person could log out, later someone else could log in and Windows might give them session 1, and then you call WTSEnumerateSessions again.  So the state might be the same as it was before, after undergoing two changes and being used by a different user than before.  Do you call this unique?  I don't know what you mean by unique.

Comment: So is there any way to get a more concrete (i.e. unique) reference to all logged in user accounts at the time?